# CSS, HTML Web Browser invalid markup tolerances

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I just opened a webpage in safari and what did I see? The whole text was green? But I only make the captions green, so the regular text should be black? Then I thought: Well I programmed this site in Firefox. At first I thought it was a bad interpretation by Safari but I reviewed my code again and I saw this:

```
<h3>Caption<h3>
<p>BlacktextblacktextBlacktextblacktextBlacktextblacktext</p>
```

I haven't closed the h3 tag.

So Safari interpreted my code correctly, and the Firefox tolerated this typo? In Firefox it works as it should: GREEN caption BLACK text; Safari says: "No no! You forgot to close the h3? Well now everything is green, deal with it."

My Question is: How tolerant are the major browsers? What (typos, invalids, etc) do the browser tolerate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, both browsers "tolerated" your invalid markup (invalid because you had two unclosed `<h3>` tags), they just did so in different ways.  Gecko (Firefox) decided that the *h3* can't contain a *p* and closed them both just before the opening *p*.  WebKit (Safari, Chrome), on the other hand probably closed them at the end of the document body.

All browsers will do their best to recover from the biggest mess of a HTML document. Their "tolerance" level is more or less equal, but the results will vary between them. It's best not to rely on browser error correction.  Use the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3c.org) to make sure your code is valid and give it the best chance of parsing correctly in all browsers.

Comment: +1 Easier to check site with a validator than thinking how tolerant browser are against invalid markup.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers doesn't have any tolerance for errors at all, but they will make their best to correct code that is not correct so that it can be rendered.

While there is well defined standards on how to render correct code, there is no standards at all on how to interpret incorrect code. Any browser may use their own plan on how to make the best out of the situation.

Neither of the browsers can interpret the code right, as the code itself is not right. So, neither of the browsers does anything wrong, they just do things differently.

Comment: " ... there is no standards at all on how to interpret incorrect code". This may be strictly true, but is somewhat misleading. The HTML5 draft describes in excruciating detail how to process any byte stream and treat it as HTML, so the next generation of browsers should all fix-up broken mark-up in the same way.

Comment: @Alohci: That's sounds promising, but that's not how it works right now. Anyhow, the code should be correct from start and not rely on error correction in the browsers to make it correct. We all know that even if the error handling will also be standardised in the future, the actual implementations will still differ...